# want to exit after tail command in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hadoop

I am using shell scripts , which performs following command

```
hadoop fs -cat /input-path/* | grep "text" | tail -1
```

I want to exit after this command, so that my shell scripts will execute another command.

Comment: How can we do this? In other cases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sed` instead to exit as soon as `text` is found:

```
sed '/text/q' <(hadoop fs -cat /input-path/*)
```

Comment: it's exiting now , but grep is not working properly.

Comment: Even `awk '/text/{print; exit}' <(hadoop fs -cat /input-path/*)` also works.